# 3d games in android

Tags: java, android

i want to create 3d games for android but i don't have any information about that. i want to do this in most advanced way like big companies. "most advanced way" means i don't use simple tools that rapidly return result but there is no way to creativity and CREATION. I need an standard way with complete resources and so on...

i want to know this too:
1- i need a game engine or i can create games with my own engine? how?
2- [important] i need to learn 3D Max or Maya etc...?

Every guidance will push me forward. Thanks

Comment: Android uses (supports?) OpenGL ES

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think ***Unity*** is the tool which you require for 3D game development.

**Unity** is the development environment that gets out of your way, allowing you to focus on simply creating your game.

Link : http://unity3d.com/unity/